# VirtualBox not booting with Windows 10 iso

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to boot Windows 10 64-bit as a guest operating system from VirtualBox. The only problem is that I get this error when trying to boot `FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted`

I really have no clue why this is happening at all. I have added the iso file to the IDE Controller in the storage settings just like all of the other answers on Ask Ubuntu suggest.

I have also tried Windows 8 and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and Use a SATA Controller in your VM **Settings > Storage**.

Check your ISO File in a terminal with: (example)

```
file data/isos/Windows81-pro_x64.iso 
data/isos/Windows81-pro_x64.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'ESD_ISO' (bootable)
```

It must look similar to this example.

Then add this iso file as an **Optical Drive** to the SATA Controller.

Comment: When I do `file Windows81_x64.iso   : ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'New folder'. it says that it is a new folder. how do I change it to a `ESD_ISO`?

Comment: Didn't see such an output before. where did you get this "iso" from ?
Please make sure that you download installation-sources from Microsoft. Not elsewhere. Maybe this link would be helpful: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-pro-iso-for-64-bit/06a251cd-8f72-4226-bd2d-f5a8935402b2?auth=1